# JavaScript - Variable and appendchild

Tags: javascript, xml, appendchild

I am programming web application for transfrorming XML documents and I need append output from my transform script to any variable.

My problem is, output is DOM and I need put it to variable. 
I tryed var x.appendChild(result), but it doesn't work. How to do it?

Sorry for my bad english :)

---

Edit:

Okey, here is my code:

```
function transform(){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="";

var xml=editor.getValue();
var xsl=editor2.getValue();
var result = "XML and Query fields are required.";
if(xml && xsl){
    if (window.DOMParser)
      {
      var parser=new DOMParser();
      xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
      xslDoc=parser.parseFromString(xsl,"text/xml");
      }
    else // Internet Explorer
      {
      xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async="false";
      xmlDoc.loadXML(xml);

      xslDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xslDoc.async="false";
      xslDoc.loadXML(xsl);
      }

    try{
        // code for IE
        if (window.ActiveXObject)
          {

          result=xmlDoc.transformNode(xslDoc);
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=result;
          }
        // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
        else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
          {

        xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
        xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslDoc);
        result = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc,document);
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(result);




          }
    }
    catch(e){
            result += e;
    }

}
```

}

Result is transformed XML document by XSL file. 
I need put output of this code to the webpage like a plain text. That means code with html tags.
In this case is target object, result, DIV and it shows formated text. Just like a html page, but I need show complete text with tags.

My idea was put result to the textarea. It wokrs, text will shows, but without tags. I tryed use

```
var t=document.createTextNode(result);
document.getElementById("result").appendChild(t);
```

but I get error message... Something like [object DocumentFragment].
Any ideas? Next variable is just my experiment, not good way.

Comment: what do you mean put it in a variable? you can store dom elements in variables. show us more code please. how did you get `result`?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
var xml;
xml = '<someElement>SomeValue</someElement>';
document.body.innerHTML += xml;
```

or slightly more generically:

```
var xml;
// function definition
function addToDOM (xml, output) {
    output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML || "";
    output.innerHTML += xml;
    return output;
}
// example usage
xml = '<someElement>SomeValue</someElement>';
addToDOM(xml, document.body);
```